# How to fix index error when querying GAE datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

When I try to run a query on the datastore ordered by date I get the following error:

```
NeedIndexError: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:

- kind: Message
  properties:
  - name: author
  - name: ref
  - name: date
```

The query runs without error if I don't try to order by date. The appengine console under datastore indexes says:

```
author ▲ , ref ▲ , date ▼   
Serving
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I run my query ordered by date? Thanks!

Here is my entity definition:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Message(ndb.Model):
    subject = ndb.StringProperty()
    body = ndb.TextProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    ref = ndb.StringProperty( required=True )
    author = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)
```

and this is the query that fails:

```
def readMessages( ref, user = None ):
    query = Message.query()
    query = query.filter(Message.ref == ref )
    if user:
        query = query.filter(Message.author == user.key )
    query = query.order(Message.date)

# convert to a list so we can index like an array
return [ message for message in query ]
```

My index.yaml contains:

```
indexes:

- kind: Message
  properties:
  - name: author
  - name: ref
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the "direction" as well because "ordering" is done when index is written to speed things up in Google's style.

So, your index.yaml should be like:

```
indexes:

- kind: Message
  properties:
  - name: author
  - name: ref
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

Here's Google's official description about order:

> The direction to sort, either asc for ascending or desc for
>   descending. This is only required for properties used in sort orders
>   of the query, and must match the direction used by the query. The
>   default is asc.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I forgot to copy the last line of my index definition. The app engine console indicates the index has been created as ref ▲ , author ▲ , date ▼ . So I don't think this is my problem, but I have updated the index definition in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Lawrence, you got me on the right track- I think I have found the answer. The query must EXACTLY match the index definition.

I discovered this by trying different GQL queries in the datastore admin box.

For example, the following 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Message where ref='' and author='' order by date 
SELECT * FROM Message where ref='' and author='' order by date asc
```

both fail with:

```
no matching index found.

The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: Message
  properties:
  - name: author
  - name: ref
  - name: date
```

However,

```
SELECT * FROM Message where ref='' and author='' order by date desc
```

succeeds. Likewise, queries which have less parameters than the index contains will also fail, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM Message where ref='' order by date DESC
```

fails with:

```
no matching index found.

The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: Message
  properties:
  - name: ref
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

So the problem was in my query, the line:

```
query = query.order(Message.date)
```

is actually sorting in ascending order, but my index says DESCENDING order. The fix is:

```
query = query.order(-Message.date)
```

Comment: you're welcome! yes that must be an exact match of your query and the index order.